# How are collective tags chosen?

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

I was looking over the Go Collective and its tags and noticed some tags that (from my quick research looking at tag wikis or googling them) felt kind of out of place.

Namely I noticed [go-cd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-cd) and [go-back-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-back-n) being added to the Go Collective, but seemingly not fitting.

GoCD (https://www.gocd.org/) appears to be an open source [CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) server that doesn't look like it has connections to Google Go to me and Go-Back-N ARQ has a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go-back-n/info) and [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-Back-N_ARQ) that state no connection to Google Go whatsoever, but instead an instance of a protocol.

To me it seems like someone just searched for tags containing "Go" and selected all of them. Could this just be an oversight as part of a product launch? Yes, it probably is. But to me it raises the questions:

- Who can select tags for a collective?
- Are tags vetted by tag participants or Stack Overflow before being added to a collective?
- In the future when this is more widely adopted, will there be a way to let someone know that a tag doesn't fit? Can users flag this directly, do we reach out to Meta, Stack Exchange Support or the collective company directly?

Comment: Perfect time to create a [go-away] tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao oh, now we know who to blame for a disambiguation request 10 years from now when somebody has a bright idea to name their technology like this :)

Comment: Thanks for catching this! I've let the Team know about these two tags internally and I'll see if we can get more of an explanation here about how it works. In general, Collectives should only include tags that are about products controlled/owned by the organization administrating the Collective, so you shouldn't see cases like this.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. This is indeed an oversight and we'll adjust it.

The tags are selected by Stack Overflow employees, and based on whether an organization builds, supports, and has authority over a technology. We then discuss and vet it with the customer.

This is (for now) a fairly manual process, and even though several people checked, sadly these things slip through the cracks. Luckily adjusting it shouldn't be too difficult so I expect this to be fixed relatively fast.

Currently, the best way of letting us know is by letting us know on Meta (just like you did). Both if you want to dispute the fact that a tag is added to a Collective, as if you feel there is a tag missing from one. When this is widely adopted probably we'll need to have a more scalable flag system, but for the Beta phase, Meta should be fine.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to add the [tag:firebase] tag to the google cloud collective. Currently, it contains both [tag:google-cloud-firestore] tag and [tag:firebase-realtime-database] tag which are products included in Firebase.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yeah, I was surprised to find [pyrebase] (a Python wrapper for Firebase) was included but [firebase] is not, for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! It's done :)